Measuring treatment heterogeneity
This follows on a first question posted here
I am looking at the effect of information on local prices and choices to move to certain cities. I think that this information will have a positive effect on my outcome (moving) for those who are positively surprised (they think that local prices are higher than they actually are) and a negative one for those that are negatively surprised (they think  local prices are cheaper than they actually are). I can measure both prior and posterior beliefs for the treatment group, but obviously not for the control one. Can I still explore the effect of treatment by looking at heterogeneity of whether people were positively or negatively surprised ?
Ie, does  does it  estimate:
Movei​=β0​+β1​Treatmenti​+β2​PosSurprisei​×Treatmenti​+β3​NegSurprisei​×Treatmenti​+ei​
Heterogeneity would, for me, entail comparing with the control group, but I cannot get my head around this case.
Edit : If I am able to fond data on prior (but not posterior) beliefs, I could add this as a a control, as a thought
